# 403 Forbidden For only SOME folders/objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm making a craft site and most of my images work fine, but some images in some of my s3 folders are returning 403 forbidden errors.

Here is my policy

{

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::extendednotesimages",
                "arn:aws:s3:::extendednotesimages/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is that a policy attached to a user or role? Is there a bucket policy? Are the objects owned by the same AWS account that the S3 bucket is in?

Comment: @jordanm Yes all the images are within the same bucket. Attached to a user group with one user which is what Craft is using. I'm not 100% on if the objects are owned by the same account but I would assume yes. I am also running locally